# Live preview in the new Xcode 15

Tags: xcode

How can I display the live preview in the new Xcode 15 Storyboard? The live preview that displays the UI on different devices at the same time (iPhone 13, iPhone 13 Pro Max, iPad etc, all on the same time). Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFDo0.png

In Xcode 14 I could use Command + Option + Enter ↩ in assistant to open the live preview, but that does not work anymore.

Comment: Anyone find out how to get the live preview back?

Comment: I have this problem too, I don't understand if it's a bug...

Comment: If you select "Editor > Assistant" and then, when the assistant has focus, "Editor > Preview", the preview should appear in place of the assistant, but for me it closes without apparently doing anything...

Comment: @gidanmx2 Exactly what is happening here also...